# Is it possible to request Instagram metrics with different periods in a single API call?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I would like to request the following [Instagram Insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/insights/) metrics using a single graph API call:

- follower_count
- audience_gender_age

The problem I am facing is that `follower_count` requires a period parameter 'day' and `audience_gender_age` a period parameter 'lifetime'. I have tried to merge them in a single API call, but this is not supported by Facebook:

```
/XXXXXX/?fields=insights.metric(follower_count).period(day),insights.metric(audience_gender_age).period(lifetime)
```

I there a proper way to request these metrics using different periods in a single API call?

Comment: You probably get an error about using the same field name twice? They have an “aliasing” syntax for that, that makes this possible in theory, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/aliasing-fields - I am not sure however if this will work properly with the different periods, you’d have to try it.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have tried it and found out that your solution also works for using different periods.

Comment: Alright, I made a short answer out of the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to request data from the same field twice in one query, that can be done using the `.as(name)` aliasing syntax, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/aliasing-fields

Quote docs,

> For example, you can retrieve an image in two sizes and alias the returned object fields as picture_small and picture_larger:
>
> ```
> me?fields=id,name,picture.width(100).height(100).as(picture_small),
>           picture.width(720).height(720).as(picture_large)
> ```